# Tamron 90mm SP Macro manual focus locks

Tags: lens, film, repair, manual-focus, tamron

I've been shooting film on a Canon AE-1 Program with a Tamron 90mm Macro SP lens. Until recently, the lens worked perfectly, but all of a sudden it won't focus farther than 10ft. To my knowledge it hasn't been dropped.

This is not my lens, and i have it checked out through school. Is there a possibility for a self- repair?

Comment: Since it belongs to the school, if it needs repair I would let them make that decision.

Answer (score 1):

There's a focus limiting switch - so that when you're doing macro work, it won't hunt through the whole range.  Look over the lens and find the switch and turn it off.

[image]

Comment: This link reviews the original Tamron SP 90mm f/2.8 Macro and discusses the focus limiting switch.    http://www.cameralabs.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=17673

Comment: Since he is using it on a Canon AE-1P I would assume he is using the original SP 90mm f/2.8 Macro, not the more current Di lens.

Comment: Right, its still a practically identically looking switch.

Comment: @MichaelClark - you were right about it being the original lens, and there is no limiting switch. After repairing a Canon FD 35-105 f/3.5-4.5, my best guess is that a screw might have come loose, or something along the lines.